# Reduce a transition matrix when using Markov chain to describe a web site activity

Tags: r, markov-process

I have log from a website describing page by page visits. So lots of data.

I would like to make a transition matrix with states each page of the site. So markov chains with continuous-time and discrete states.

It will be a huge transition matrix with a lots of states. The idea behind is to be able to represent how visitors navigate through the website.

It will make a lot of states. I would like then to reduce the number of states by aggregating them on a relevant way. aka, two pages visited the same way should go altogether.

I saw this concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpability

Now, my questions are the following:
Is there better way to look at the way people navigate on the website that I missed?
I use r and I saw the markovchain package allows to do nice stuff, like giving the probability to go from one page to another.
I didn't found a simple function to determine if two states are "lumpable". So is there some package that I am missing?

In the case of non-lumpability, how to determine which states should go altogether? Is a segmentation like k-mean on the transition matrix would make sense? (I think about replacing the diagonal coefficient by 0 and create a new variable for the segmentation)

Comment: How many unique pages are there on this website?

Comment: Around 300 unique pages. But it's fine if I work only on a sample.

Comment: Are you already combining pages with different parameters, e.g. www.website.com/articles/something.html?source=homepage and www.website.com/articles/something.html

Comment: No, and I would like an analytic proof to do so. Homepage is a huge point of attraction, this is a sure fact. :)

Comment: Clearly, some sort of dimension reducing technique would be useful in building up to the Markov analysis. A network analysis with the 300 pages as nodes would serve multiple purposes in: 1) determining node (page) centrality, 2) identifying dominant paths or chains of pages through the site, 3) defining geodesic distances or the shortest paths from node A to node F, and so on. Plenty of literature on this. A good overview is *Analyzing Social Networks* by Borgatti dealing with most network construction issues